# How much memory did Linux give to malloc()?

Tags: linux, memory-management, mmap

This is a Linux system question, not a coding question.  When I use "top" to check the memory usage of my program, it reports a value 3-4 times as large as the actual heap allocation as given by Valgrind's Massif, a memory profiler.  It's a large program, and the difference is hundreds of megabytes.  The Valgrind manual gives only a partial explanation:

> (Massif) does not directly measure memory allocated with
>   lower-level system calls such as mmap, mremap, and brk.
>
> Heap allocation functions such as malloc are built on top of these
>   system calls. For example, when needed, an allocator will typically
>   call mmap to allocate a large chunk of memory, and then hand over
>   pieces of that memory chunk to the client program in response to calls
>   to malloc et al. Massif directly measures only these higher-level
>   malloc et al calls, not the lower-level system calls.

Fine, but how much memory am I really taking away from the system?  I need to be able to run as many instances of this program as possible on one machine, so I need to know how much of that memory is still available.  Page alignment etc. cannot explain a difference of hundreds of megabytes in reported memory usage.

Also, what determines the block size of the underlying mmap() call?  I'm seeing blocks of 64MB at a time being taken according to top, which seems bizarrely large.

Comment: There is a difference between virtual memory allocations and physical memory use. In Linux top these are displayed as VIRT and RES. Use `pmap -X [pid]` for lots and lots of memory details. I doubt that those 64 MB memory blocks are actually used. They are probably virtual reservations.

Comment: It's worth noting that whenever you run a program under valgrind or asan, it allocates a lot of memory in child space for its own structures.

Answer (score 1):

Any malloc implementation will be optimised for applications with huge memory requirements, because apps with low requirements run just fine anyway, and virtual memory is cheap.

For example, you will find malloc implementations that use a block of memory for up to 1024 mallocs of up to 16 bytes, another block for up to 1024 mallocs of up to 32 bytes, and so on. With a few mallocs this is inefficient but still cheap. With gazillions of mallocs, it makes malloc very efficient.

So saying "4 times as much" can be completely pointless. Tell us how many megabytes more than you thought.